# Read FastAPI StreamableResponse from React Native client

Tags: react-native, axios, fetch, streaming, fastapi

I'm streaming an audio file chunked up using fastapi `StreamingResponse`, which when the endpoint is called from the browser/curled has the format:

```json
 {"text": "Hello John Doe!"}{"chunk": "blob_base64_data"}{"chunk": "blob_base64_data"}{"chunk": "blob_base64_data"}{"chunk": "blob_base64_data"}{"status": "success"}
```

However when I try to receive the chunks from react native, the response does not have a body and I tried a lot of combinations of axios/fetch methods, none of which work.  Here's some of the code combinations I've tried: https://pastebin.com/a9WSe00t . I've also tried a couple different `Content-Type` headers which didn't help.

Any advice on how can I stream this data in react native? Thanks!